# Why am I getting this error message: SQL Error: ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to insert data into my table with the following parameters:

```
CREATE TABLE book
  ( ISBN CHAR(10),
    Title VARCHAR2(20),
    AuthorFName VARCHAR2(20),
    AuthorLName VARCHAR2(20),
    ListPrice NUMBER(2,2),
    Qoh VARCHAR2(7),
```

Oracle Developer states that the next line is where the error starts. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
INSERT INTO book (ISBN, Title, AuthorFName, AuthorLName, ListPrice, QoH)
  VALUES(0670894370, 'A Common Life', 'Jan', 'Karon', 24.95, 45);
```

Comment: your create table statement is incomplete

Comment: You also have a typo where 47 (a number) is being inserted into Qoh (a varchar).  Did you mean `'47'`

Comment: If you find that your question has been answered, don't forget to mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

```
ListPrice NUMBER(2,2)
```

That means it has 0 digits before the decimal and 2 digits after the decimal.

You might be looking for `NUMBER(4,2)` if you want it to have 2 digits before the decimal. But i would advise you to make it bigger if it is intended to handle prices.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/95bc7/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

try this in your create table:

```
ListPrice NUMBER(4,2)
```